# VBA code error stating that object variable is not set

Tags: vba, object, runtime-error

I am using the following code to transform/sort data from an imported range to another range. All good so far except that I encounter the following error when I try to run the code:

> Run-time error '91':  Object variable or With block variable not set

Moreover, when I press the debug button it sends me to the following line:

```
rbuguri = ws.Range("A35:E999").Find("Verify Sweep / Regression").Row + 2
```

Below is the code that i am using:

```
Sub Transfer_VS_Bugs()
'
' Transfer_Bugs_To_Edit_Data Macro

Dim ws As Worksheet
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''' Change is needed '''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VS")

ws.Select
Dim lrow As Integer
lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
startrow = 35

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
rbuguri = ws.Range("A35:E999").Find("Verify Sweep / Regression").Row + 2
cbuguri = ws.Range("B3:E32").Find("Summary").Column - 1


While startrow <= lrow


    worksheet_EDIT_DATA.Cells(bugsrow, bugscolumn) = ws.Range("A" & startrow) 'for BUG ID
    worksheet_EDIT_DATA.Cells(bugsrow, bugscolumn + 1) = ws.Range("B" & startrow) ' BUG Description
    worksheet_EDIT_DATA.Cells(bugsrow, bugscolumn + 2) = ws.Range("D" & startrow) ' BUG Platform


startrow = startrow + 1
bugsrow = bugsrow + 1


Wend
ws.Activate
MsgBox "Copied, Formated and shipped" & vbNewLine & "Always remember to be carefull"
rbuguri = Nothing
cbuguri = Nothing
End Sub
```

So what's the cause?

Comment: If `ws.Range("A35:E999").Find("Verify Sweep / Regression")` does not find anything it will be nothing and then you get that error. And what are the lines `rbuguri = Nothing` and   `cbuguri = Nothing` good for? And last question: Why don't you declare all variables you use? Why only ws, lrow?

Comment: to be fair, @Storax, he also declared `ws`, but I agree with you 100%. Setting `Option Explicit` (and making it mandatory by going to `Tools` | `Options` | and ticking the `Require Variable Declaration` checkbox) will help eliminate a _lot_ of future errors.

Comment: @Storax, i thought that i need to set rbuguri and cbuguri to nothing at the end of the script to avoid the error (guess i was wrong, and thanks for pointing that out). On the other hand i've declared all variables and also added some custom text in the range but i still get that error...